Change order of navigation for `flymake-goto-next-error`
When I use flymake-goto-next-error it will move the point to the next warning or error in the buffer.
But I would like to solve errors first, then perhaps address the warnings.
So what I want is a function which navigates to the next error, skipping over any warnings. Only if there are no errors left in the buffer, should it navigate to the next warning.
I have been able to adjust the diagnostic filter like this:
(defun rvl/flymake-goto-next-error (&optional n filter interactive)
  (interactive (list 1
                     (if (not current-prefix-arg) '(:error))
                     t))
  (flymake-goto-next-error n filter interactive))

This function will find errors only, and I can use the prefix arg to find warnings. But I would like a single command to do both. This one doesn't seem to work properly:
(defun rvl/flymake-goto-next-error-warning-note (&optional n interactive)
  (interactive (list 1 t))
  (or
   (flymake-goto-next-error n '(:error))
   (flymake-goto-next-error n '(:warning :note))
   (flymake-goto-next-error n '(:error :warning :note) interactive)))

One problem I had is that the return value of flymake-goto-next-error isn't very useful when called interactively. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.

If you look at the code of flymake-goto-next-error, you will see that it basically loops over all the flymake-diagnostic overlays, first constructing a list of them (possibly filtered), and then sorting them by the overlay start position. I would start with a modified function that does a second sort on that result based on the severity. Assuming that the sort is stable, that would put all errors first (in order of the overlay start position) and then the rest (also in order of the start position). I did not try to implement this, so untested.
